# Having trouble with my Tkinter/Sqlite Python app

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm in the beggining stage of writing an address book app.  When I run the app and enter in a first, last name and hit add I get an error message.  Nothing getts added to database.

Here is the error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "address.py", line 13, in addName
    (last_name, first_name))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('address.db')
c = conn.cursor() 
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS address (lastName TEXT, firstName TEXT )''') 
conn.commit 

def addName(event):

    c.execute("INSERT INTO address (lastName, firstName) VALUES (?,?)",
            (last_name, first_name))

    conn.commit()

root = Tk()
root.title('Address Book')
Label(root, text='First Name').grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=4)
first_name = Entry(root)
first_name.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Label(root, text='Last Name').grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=4)
last_name = Entry(root).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

getNameButton = Button(root, text='Add')
getNameButton.bind('<Button-1>', addName)
getNameButton.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

TIA,

Gabriel

Comment: hint: you can't store a widget in the database, only the value stored in a widget. Ask yourself what is the datatype of first_name and last_name.

Comment: I realize what I'm effectively doing is trying to store a widget in the database.  What I need to do is to store the First and Last name from the widget into the database?  How would I do that?

Comment: Read some documentation on the `Entry` widget, and search this website. You're asking questions that have been asked numerous times and is covered in many sites that document how to use tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help:
c.execute('INSERT INTO address (lastname, firstname) VALUES (?,?)', ([last_name,first_name]))

Comment: I got sqlite to take my input.  I now am stuck on how to pass a variable from  Tkinter into SQLite.

Comment: If you're using an entry box then you can act a textvariable. For instance, my_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = first_name). You can then use first_name.get() to retrieve whatever is written in the entry. If you need a resource, I would try effbot.org to explain all the properties of entries